# JSF of java support for HTML5

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Is it possible to use JSF(Java EE) to create html5 pages instead of xhtml ? 
If so are there many support issues due to html5 ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there isn't build-in support for html5.
All components are rendered as XHTML.
But you can alter these components to produce html5 and create new that support it.
See [ICEfaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/).
There are number of controls out there that support already html5.

An insteresting article series can be found here [JSF 2 fu: HTML5 composite components](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-1010/?ca=drs-)